# Passing arguement to an event in dojo 1.7+

Tags: javascript, dojo, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to pass an argument to an event in dojo 1,7+.
suppose I have the following module:

```
define(
        [ "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dijit/registry", "js/busyIndicator",
          "dojox/mobile/ListItem", "dojo/dom-class",
          "ppwidgets/MyCommunitesRecentListItem", "js/utils" 
        ],
        function(dom, domStyle, registry, busyIndicator, ListItem, 
                 domClass, MyCommunitesRecentListItem, utils) {

            return {
                sortBy: function(sortType) {

            }};
        }
);

<h3>In html:</h3>
```

In normal html I can do that: onClick="sortBy('date')"
**but in dojo, I have to use this:**
data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _sortBy" 
I want to bind the function sortBy( ) to a button, How can I pass the sortType to sortBy( ) function.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Dojo provides a function called **partial()**. Look [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-partial) and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/hitch/) for documentation and tutorial.

Basically what it allows is to attach arguments permanently to the function.
so your code would look something like this.

```
define(
        [ "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dijit/registry", "js/busyIndicator",
          "dojox/mobile/ListItem", "dojo/dom-class",
          "ppwidgets/MyCommunitesRecentListItem", "js/utils" ,
          "dojo/_base/lang" // need to add this module.
        ],
        function(dom, domStyle, registry, busyIndicator, ListItem, 
                 domClass, MyCommunitesRecentListItem, utils, lang) {

            var myFunc = function( sortType ) {
            };
            var partialFunc = lang.partial (myFunc, sortType );

            return {
                sortBy: partialFunc 
            };
        }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  this to do it programatically, but how pass the argument throw html for example: input type="button" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _sortBy('date')"

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the argument `sortType` as an attribute in the corresponding HTML element and can access it by `event.target.sortType` in the function. This is the way that I am using currently

If you have found a way to pass parameters to function using `data-dojo-attach-event` then please add your answer. :)